# javacard byte array max length

Tags: arrays, javacard

What is the maximum size when defining a byte array in java card?

In my 32k java card, I defined a byte array with length of (9*1024) and I got 6A 84 error (Not enough memory space in the file), Also when I define it with length of (8*1024) there is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on where you allocate the array (persistent memory, transient memory) and on the available memory on your specific card. The technical limit for an array's size in Java Card is 32767 elements, because array indices are of type `short` and can only be non-negative values.

You can get an approximation of the available memory available on your card through the method `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(...)`.

Note that it is possible to set a maximum volatile/non-volatile memory size limit during applet installation. So you may be running into a limit that has been set during installation of this specific application. For instance, with gpshell, the parameters of the install command to set memory limits are

- `-nvCodeLimit ...` for the maximul non-volatile code memory
- `-nvDataLimit ...` for the maximul non-volatile data memory
- `-vDataLimit ...` for the maximul volatile data memory

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I write byte[] temp = new byte[9*1024]; in constructor. So is it persistent or transient?

Comment: @HanaBizhani Objects (including arrays) that you allocate using the `new` keyword will always be applocated in persistent memory. Keep in mind that Java Cards normally do not have garbage collection, so once allocated such arrays will exist until the application is uninstalled regardless of their visibility/accessibility.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Many cards do implement GC nowadays, but keep in mind that 1) you need to explicitly request GC using a system call, 2) GC will only run - if implemented - after a reset and 3) GC make take more time than you expect, as it requires compacting persistent memory, which is relatively slow.

Comment: @MichaelRoland I tried getting available memory with these 2 lines: 1)JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT); 2)JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_TRANSIENT_DESELECT);

The results were 22 10 and 09 DD respectively,
but still can't define a byte array with the size of byte[9*1024]
How can I convert 22 10 and 09 DD in order to know how much memory remains? 
Regards

Comment: `22 10` (hex) is 8720 in decimal so that's less than 9216 (9*1024) bytes (note that an array might have additional overhead besides the actual data). `09 DD` (hex) is 2525 in decimal. Values are in bytes.

Comment: @HanaBizhani Understanding hex is more or less a requirement if you are going to program Java Card. OK, I learned hex when my mom read out the machine code for an MSX game from a book, but even without help of your mom it should be doable, otherwise use a scientific calculator :)

Answer (score 2):

You may have a file cap set. You can check to see how much available memory you have by doing the following:

`JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT);`

see this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2254687?tstart=0)